# Get variable of another function within a

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have the following function:

```
function charts(a, b, c){

//get the variables of function values and do some stuff with it

}
```

I get variables through a, b, c already from another function start:

```
function start(){
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var c = 3;
 charts(a, b, c);
 }
```

How can I use the variables of this function inside my function charts:

```
function values() {

    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + "/?key=XXX&email=" + email + "&values=yes" + '&callback=?',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            value1 = data.value1;
            value2 = data.value2;
            value3 = data.value3;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Call `charts` in your `success` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function charts(a, b, c){
  //get the variables of function values and do some stuff with it
}

function values(){

  $.ajax({
    url: site_url + "/?key=XXX&email=" + email + "&values=yes" + '&callback=?',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      value1 = data.value1;
      value2 = data.value2;
      value3 = data.value3;
      charts(value1, value2, value3);
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to pass values to charts and then call the ajax request and use `a`, `b` and `c` in the callback you try something like that:

```
function charts(a, b, c) {
  return function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: site_url + "/?key=XXX&email=" + email + "&values=yes" + '&callback=?',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        value1 = data.value1;
        value2 = data.value2;
        value3 = data.value3;
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var chartsFunction = charts(1,2,3);
chartsFunction();
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: it is more complicated because I get variables through a, b, c already from another function. is it possible to add them?

Comment: @Maddin Okay. Got it. It is only if you can edit the function `chart`

Comment: I edited my answer. Does it help?